# Images won't center

Tags: html, css, image, center

I am trying to center my images, but nothing I have tried works :(

Here is the CSS:

```css
#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
}

#slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
    opacity:0.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
    opacity:1.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}
#slideshow, #slideshow2, #slideshow3 {
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    width:267px;
}
.contentImages{
    border:1px solid #CCC; 
    padding:10px; 
    margin:20px auto 0; 
    position:relative; 
    width:804px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

And the HTML:

```html
<div class="contentImages">
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img src="upload/<?php echo $array['image'] ?>" height="200" class="active" />
        <img src="upload/<?php echo $array['image2'] ?>" height="200" />
        <img src="upload/<?php echo $array['image3'] ?>" height="200" />
     </div>
</div>
```

I have tried `text-align`, `valign`, `margin 0 auto` with a relative postion and a width, nothing :( any one have any ideas?

Comment: If you kept `position:absolute;` there it will never work.

Comment: Correct! position:absolute; removes inherited layout rules.

Comment: Use good old `<center>`, it works always and cross browser! :-) Other's will kill me for that, but the bunch of css overkill instead of one small, simple obsolete `<center>` :-) .... it's not worth it, unless you love to spend hours making your working code also valid :-)

Comment: I took out the position:absoulte, but now how do i get it stay in the same position....look at http://www.willruppelglass.com/index.php so see what I am talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know you layout details, but `text-align: center;` on the container should work, unless the images are absolute positioned. Try replacing the rules for `#slideshow` and `#slideshow IMG` with this:

```css
#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    text-align: center;
}

#slideshow img {
    z-index:8;
    opacity:0.0;
}
```