# Centering an image with CSS position absolute

Tags: html, css, image, center, alignment

I have an 3 images inside a div and that div is inside another div...like so

```
<div class="contentImages">

<div id="slideshow">

<img src="upload/<?php echo $array['image'] ?>" height="200" class="active" />

<img src="upload/<?php echo $array['image2'] ?>" height="200" />

<img src="upload/<?php echo $array['image3'] ?>" height="200" />

</div>
</div>
```

if you goto http://www.willruppelglass.com/ you can see that its a slideshow and the images are not centered inside the div and it looks horrible...

(my original plan was to have the images attaching, but I am not sure if that is possible...is it?)

Here is the CSS for the slideshow

```
#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
}

#slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
    opacity:0.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
    opacity:1.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}

#slideshow, #slideshow2, #slideshow3 {
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    width:250px;
}
```

and the CSS for content Images

```
.contentImages{
    border:1px solid #CCC; 
    padding:10px; 
    margin:20px auto 0; 
    position:relative;
    width:750px; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I hope this makes sense, this issue has been bugging me for days,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Images won't center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998535/images-wont-center)

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice. If you want to call attention for your question, edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a page for you: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center

Also, I suggest you make thumbnails of the images. It takes a painfully long time to load them, and the slideshow switches multiple times before all images is loaded.